# Kohana validation complete rules list

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.0

i can't find complete list of kohana validation rules list, can someone point me to the right documentation page? btw if some one doesn't understand what i'm talking about:

```
        return Validation::factory($arr)
            ->rule('tenant_last_name', 'not_empty')->rule('tenant_first_name', 'not_empty') // Name
            ->rule('tenant_ssn', 'not_empty')->rule('tenant_ssn', 'numeric') //SNN
            ->rule('tenant_email', 'email')->rule('tenant_email', 'not_empty') //Email
            ->rule('tenant_phone', 'numeric')->rule('tenant_phone', 'not_empty') //phone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As matino said you can look directly into the API or in the guide for an easier to read version http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/validation#provided-rules

Answer (score 0):

Look here - http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Valid